# Database does not display data correctly

Tags: java, android, database, user-interface, android-recyclerview

I have a problem, namely, I have an application that displays in the RecyclerView 2 types of salads and after pressing, one of them should show a view showing their exact details with the option of whether or not we like it. These data are obviously retrieved from the database. And everything works until we just go to a detailed view - when we click on the picture of Greek salad we get a blank view, but what is interesting when we click on the chicken salad we get just a view of Greek salad? So where does the view of the chicken salad? And why the views turned into places. I attach the code at the bottom with the pictures so that you can understand exactly what the problem is.

***DatabaseHelper***

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final String DB_NAME = "app";
private static final int DB_VERSION = 1;

public MiodzioDatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE SALAD (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
            + "NAME TEXT, "
            + "IMAGE_RESOURCE_ID INTEGER, "
            + "FAVORITE INTEGER);");

    insertSalatki(db, "Greek salad", R.drawable.salad_greek, 0);
    insertSalatki(db, "Chicken salad", R.drawable.salad_chicken, 0);

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}

private static void insertSalatki(SQLiteDatabase db, String name, int resourceId, int favorite){

    ContentValues saladValues = new ContentValues();
    salatkiValues.put("NAME", name);
    salatkiValues.put("IMAGE_RESOURCE_ID", resourceId);
    salatkiValues.put("Favorite", favorite);
    db.insert("SALAD", null, salatkiValues);
}
```

}

***Salad***

```
  public class Salad {

    private String name;
    private int imageResourceId;


    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getImageResourceId() {
        return imageResourceId;
    }

    public void setImageResourceId(int imageResourceId) {
        this.imageResourceId = imageResourceId;
    }
}
```

***SaladDetailActivity***

```
public class SaladDetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public static final String EXTRA_SALAD = "salad";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_salatki_detail);

    int salads = (Integer) getIntent().getExtras().get(EXTRA_SALAD); 

    try {

        SQLiteOpenHelper miodzioDatabaseHelper = new MiodzioDatabaseHelper(this);
        SQLiteDatabase db = miodzioDatabaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();


        Cursor cursor = db.query("SALATKI",
                new String[]{"NAME", "IMAGE_RESOURCE_ID", "FAVORITE"},
                "_id = ?",
                new String[]{Integer.toString(salads)},
                null, null, null);

        if(cursor != null) {
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {

                do {

                  String nameText = cursor.getString(0);
                   int photoId = cursor.getInt(1);

                    boolean isFavorite = (cursor.getInt(2) == 1);

                    TextView name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.salad_text);
                    name.setText(nameText);

                    ImageView photo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.salad_image);
                    photo.setImageResource(photoId);
                    photo.setContentDescription(nameText);

                    CheckBox favorite = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.favorite);
                    favorite.setChecked(isFavorite);
                }while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }
        }

        cursor.close();
        db.close();

    }catch (SQLiteException e){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Database does not work!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }


    Toolbar myChildToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_child_toolbar_salad_detail);
    setSupportActionBar(myChildToolbar);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}



@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_create_order:
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, AddActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        default:

            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


}

public void onFavoriteClicked(View view) {

    int salads = (Integer) getIntent().getExtras().get(EXTRA_SALAD);

    CheckBox favorite = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.favorite);

    ContentValues saladValues = new ContentValues();


    saladValues.put("FAVORITE", favorite.isChecked());

    SQLiteOpenHelper databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);

    SQLiteDatabase db = databaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    db.update("SALAD", saladValues,
            "_id = ?", new String[]{Integer.toString(salads)});
    db.close();
}
```

}

***SaladMaterialFragment***

```
 public class SaladMaterialFragment extends Fragment {


    private DatabaseHelper dataBaseHelper;
    private Cursor cursor;

    private ArrayList<Salad> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        RecyclerView saladRecyler = (RecyclerView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_salad_material, container, false);

        try{
            SQLiteOpenHelper databaseHelper = new databaseHelper(inflater.getContext());
            SQLiteDatabase db = databaseHelper.getReadableDatabase();

            cursor = db.query("SALAD",
                    new String[] {"NAME", "IMAGE_RESOURCE_ID"},
                    null, null, null, null, null);

            if(cursor != null){
                if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
                    do{
                        Salad salads = new Salad();
                        salad.setName(cursor.getString(0));
                        salad.setImageResourceId(cursor.getInt(1));
                        arrayList.add(salad);

                    }while (cursor.moveToNext());
                }
            }

        }catch (SQLiteException e){
            Toast.makeText(inflater.getContext(), "Database does not work!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

            CaptionedImagesAdapter adapter = new CaptionedImagesAdapter(getActivity(), arrayList);
            saladRecyler.setAdapter(adapter);

             GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 2);
            saladRecyler.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);

            adapter.setListener(new CaptionedImagesAdapter.Listener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(int position) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), SaladDetailActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra(SaladDetailActivity.EXTRA_SALAD, position);
                    getActivity().startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
        return salatkaRecyler;
        }

    }
```

***SaladDetailLayout***

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.hfad.SaladDetailActivity">


<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/my_child_toolbar_salad_detail"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/salatki_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"/>


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/salad_image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/favorite"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/favorite"
    android:onClick="onFavoriteClicked"/>
```

[image]

***So when I click on Salad greek, I get an empty view only with the option of whether it is a favorite. And when I hit the chicken salad I get a view of the Greek Salad. I have no idea what's going on?***

[image]

[image]

Comment: I dont see your recyclerview or the adapter. Are you sure you are using them?

Comment: Speaking for myself, but I don't think we need the Screenshots. I would like to see the Layout xml content.

Comment: @msecilmis 
You are correct, my mistake twice I've copied the SaladDetailActivity code, I've already fixed it, there should also be a SaladFragment class and it's RecyclerView. I added a RecyclerAdapter class in which I have an interface listener.

Comment: @Barns52 
I added layouts the way you asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is in the onClick method in SaladMaterialFragment class.
You are passing the position of the item, and in **ArrayList indexing is starting with 0**.
But in Database insertion, _id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, **Database indexing will start with 1**.
So you need to change onClick method with below.

```
adapter.setListener(new CaptionedImagesAdapter.Listener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(int position) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), SaladDetailActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra(SaladDetailActivity.EXTRA_SALAD, position+1);
                getActivity().startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

Just change **position** with **position+1**.

Comment: Thank you man! This is exactly what I was looking for! Everything works as it should :)

Answer (score 0):

Also you are inserting the `int` value of your `drawable` resource which is not a good idea. This value is not necessarily constant throughout the life of your app -- a later version may issue a new value to this resource.
So please do not do this.

```
insertSalatki(db, "Greek salad", R.drawable.salad_greek, 0);
```

Instead map the `drawable` to an independent yet constant reference. Some thing like:

```
insertSalatki(db, "Greek salad", idSaladGreek, 0);
```

So, since you have potentially many rows in your database with the same salad type (eg. Greek Salad) with potentially many different resource ids, when you query your database for a salad type yon might be getting the wrong resource id. This might be causing the problem of you not being able to display your image.

Test this by comparing the `int` value coming from the database (`int photoId = cursor.getInt(1)`) and the `int` value of `R.drawable.salad_greek`.

In your `SaladDetailActivity` you should also check to see if you are getting a valid value for:

```
int salads = (Integer) getIntent().getExtras().get(EXTRA_SALAD);
```

Comment: "In your DatabaseHelper class it appears as if you are inserting a new row each time you call this class? I see no UNIQUE constraints for the this table. If so you will be increasing your apps storage footprint and filling you database with useless data as well as potentially invalid data." So what I must do? 
I'm just learning the databases and not exactly what it's all about.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion of changing the int to drawable, I already did it."Test this by comparing the int value coming from the database (int photoId = cursor.getInt(1)) and the int value of R.drawable.salad_greek." - so my int photoId call me Salad Greek, so where is Salad Chicken?     I don't know where is a problem.